# Is an XOR swap equivalent to a traditional swap in all cases?

Tags: java, string, bit-manipulation, swap, bitwise-xor

Below is a method which performs an ‘in place ' string reverse i.e. Black Cat becomes Cat Black.
 In the second swap section if a traditional swap (commented out) is used all tests pass however if an XOR swap is used only one test passes.

Is it not possible to simply 'swap'

```
        for (int i = count; i <= (end + count) / 2; i++) {
            char temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[end - (i - count)];
            arr[end - (i - count)] = temp;
        }
```

to

```
        for (int i = count; i <= (end + count) / 2; i++) {
            arr[i] ^= arr[end - (i - count)];
            arr[end - (i - count)] ^= arr[i];
            arr[i] ^= arr[end - (i - count)];
        }
```

Method

```
public class ReverseString {

    public static char[] revString(String input) {

        char[] arr = input.toCharArray();
        int length = arr.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < (length / 2); i++) {
            arr[i] ^= arr[length - i - 1];
            arr[length - i - 1] ^= arr[i];
            arr[i] ^= arr[length - i - 1];  
        }

        int end;
        int charCount;
        int count = 0;
        while (count < length) {

            if (arr[count] != ' ') {

                charCount = 0;              
                while (count + charCount < length && arr[count + charCount] != ' ') {
                    charCount++;
                }

                end = count + charCount - 1;

//              for (int i = count; i <= (end + count) / 2; i++) {
//                  char temp = arr[i];
//                  arr[i] = arr[end - (i - count)];
//                  arr[end - (i - count)] = temp;
//              }

                for (int i = count; i <= (end + count) / 2; i++) {
                    arr[i] ^= arr[end - (i - count)];
                    arr[end - (i - count)] ^= arr[i];
                    arr[i] ^= arr[end - (i - count)];
                }

                count += charCount;

            } else {
                count++;
            }           
        }
        return arr;
    }   
}
```

Test

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class ReverseStringTest {

    @Test
    @Parameters(method = "getStrings")
    public void testRevString(String testValue, char[] expectedValue) {     
        assertThat(ReverseString.revString(testValue), equalTo(expectedValue));     
    }

    private static final Object[] getStrings() {
        return new Object[] {
            new Object[] {"Black Cat", "Cat Black".toCharArray()},
            new Object[] {"left to", "to left".toCharArray()}
        };
    }   
}
```

Output for fail

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: ["C", "a", "t", " ", "B", "l", "a", "c", "k"]
but: was ["C", "
```

Comment: Actually write a swap method (`static void swap(char[] arr, int i, int j)`) and test that by itself.

Comment: The output appears to be an array of Strings, not an array of `char`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice one test passes using XOR swap and both using traditional swap. The total length of the String seems to be the deciding factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XOR swap fails when swapping a value with itself. Here's your code:

```
arr[i] ^= arr[end - (i - count)];
arr[end - (i - count)] ^= arr[i];
arr[i] ^= arr[end - (i - count)];
```

Let's assume that `i == end - (i - count)`. Then:

```
arr[i] ^= arr[end - (i - count)];
```

sets `arr[i]` to zero (since anything XOR'd with itself is zero).

The next two lines then do nothing, as XOR'ing with zero has no effect, leaving `arr[i]` as zero and thus corrupting your input.

Whether the above assumption is ever true depends on the length of the input, as you noted.

Because of this gotcha, XOR swapping is dangerous. Since it's also hard to read, and isn't a performance win on any modern platform, this micro-optimization trick is obsolete and should be avoided.